# How to delete element with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

Is it possible to delete element from loaded `DOM` without creating a new one? For example something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    if($href->nodeValue == 'First')
        //delete
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Can't remove node from DomDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602207/php-cant-remove-node-from-domdocument)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You remove the node by telling the parent node to remove the child:

```
$href->parentNode->removeChild($href);
```

See [`DOMNode::$parentNode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) and [`DOMNode::removeChild()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/DOMNode.removeChild).

See as well:

- [How to remove attributes using PHP DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619282/how-to-remove-attributes-using-php-domdocument)
- [How to remove an HTML element using the DOMDocument class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171597/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-the-domdocument-class)

Comment: Yes, there are not many options how to do that. I now added some links so to make it an actual answer, but this actually smells like a duplicate candidate. At least one should pick some good related question.

Answer (score 42):

This took me a while to figure out, so here's some clarification:

If you're deleting elements from within a loop (as in the OP's example), **you need to loop backwards**

```
$elements = $completePage->getElementsByTagName('a');
for ($i = $elements->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
  $href = $elements->item($i);
  $href->parentNode->removeChild($href);
}
```

> [DOMNodeList documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390): You can modify, and even delete, nodes from a DOMNodeList if you iterate backwards

Comment: You saved me a lot of head scratching. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Easily:

```
$href->parentNode->removeChild($href);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered but I wanted to add to it.

In case someone faces the same problem I have faced.

Looping through the domnode list and removing items directly can cause issues.

I just read this and based on that I created a method in my own code base which works:https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php

Here is what I would do:

```
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$links_to_remove = [];

foreach($links as $link){
    $links_to_remove[] = $link;
}

foreach($links_to_remove as $link){
    $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}

$dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Yes. This is very important. https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292

Answer (score 0):

for remove tag or somthing.

```
removeChild($element->id());
```

full example:

```
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl('URL');
$html = $dom->find('main')[0];
$html2 = $html->find('p')[0];
$span = $html2->find('span')[0];


$html2->removeChild($span->id());

echo $html2;
```