# PHP How remove element from html dom?

Tags: php, html, dom

We have **index.php** with code:

```
<div class="test"> text text text text</div>
<div class="test2"> text text text text</div>
<div class="test3"> text text text text</div>
<div class="test4"> text text text text</div>
```

In file **test.php** we use code:

```
ob_start(); // start output buffer
include 'index.php';
$template = ob_get_contents(); // get contents of buffer
ob_end_clean();
return $template;
```

Tell me please how remove div with class `test2` and all content in him from html which we get in `$template`?

P.S.: we want remove div with class `test2` regardless of the attributes inside the div tag.

Comment: have you looked into jQuery?

Comment: PHP has a built-in DOM library you can use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: @webdad3 The OP is looking to process HTML on the server before sending it out to the client. jQuery won't help here.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument

Comment: or try and use a regex or string match to remove it

Comment: @webdad3 only php need

Comment: @Dai how get content with DOMDocument and and will there be faster this function than get_contents() ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have a html structure in a variable. You can remove this with a preg_replace.

```
$template = preg_replace('/<div.*?class="test2".*?>.*?</div>/','', $template);
```

Another way is to use a DOM parser.

Comment: but how been if div have more attributes? we would be remove div with clss `test2` regardless of the attributes inside the div tag.

Comment: I will edit this for situation with many attributes