# PHP - delete parent which contains specific text

Tags: php, xpath, extract

**HTML:**

```
<div class="vm-customfield-cart">
     <span class="product-field-type-S">Some important text</span><br />
     <span class="product-field-type-S">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br />
</div>
```

How to remove just span which contains text `Lorem ipsum`. Everything after `Lorem ipsum` can be variable, thats why i need to search jsut by `Lorem ipsum`.

My code looks like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$spanNodeList = $xp->query("//*[contains(., 'Lorem ipsum')]");

foreach ($spanNodeList as $spanNode) {
    //I have no idea how to clean it out
}
```

**End result should looks like:**

```
<div class="vm-customfield-cart">
     <span class="product-field-type-S">Some important text</span><br />
</div>
```

Comment: maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15272752/3615630

Comment: `//span[starts-with(., 'Lorem ipsum')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$spanNode->parentNode->removeChild($spanNode);
```