# How to remove specific dom element with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have this html in my database:

```
<p>some text 1</p>
<img src=\"http://www.example.com/images/some_image_1.jpg\">
<p>some text 2</p>
<p>some text 3</p>
<img src=\"http://www.example.com/images/some_image_2.jpg\">
<p>some text 4</p>
<p>some text 5</p>
<img src=\"http://www.example.com/images/some_image_3.jpg\">
```

Conditionally, I need to remove some specific `<img>` tag. So I don't want to remove all `<img>` tags, but only specific ones.

I have tried this, but it will remove all `<img>` tags, even if I do not want that:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

for($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $image = $nodes->item($i);
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
```

Can someone help me with this ? In this html example, let's say that I want to remove first and third image in text, but to leave second one.

Also, I have noticed that `saveHTML()` method is adding `<html><body>` tags to my html, and I do not want that. I don't see any option to turn this off. Any help there too ?

Thanks in advance, I'm stuck with this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using array. I modified your code this will not remove second img tag.

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Declare array with numeric vlaues
$remainImages = array(1);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

  for($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i,$remainImages) {
        $image = $nodes->item($i);
        $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
     }  
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Your code will keep second and third image for some reason. I have found a way to make it work. Inside the for loop I create the array of images to remove. Then in additional foreach loop I go through that array and remove images.

Comment: Yes second will image will remain above in code but not third. So you need to make sure 2 is not added into this array.
 `$remainImages = array(1);`

Comment: It is not working as intended. Look here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rkim-st8w , run the code.

Comment: I found issue in my code, please pass 2 into array if you want to retain second image like below.

`$remainImages = array(2);`

So please if you want to retain 8 and 14 then 

`$remainImages = array(8,14);`

Answer (score 1):

there are option to avoid adding html and body tag when you want to load an html file or content:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('file.html'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
//@$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html'); //Adds Html and body tags if not exist at the beginning

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach($nodes as $i => $node){
    if ($i == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $image = $nodes->item($i);
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
}

return $dom->saveHTML();
//$dom->saveHtmlFile('file.html');
```

some answers close to your question's answer which used in this answer:

1. To delete element(you already used):
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/15272752/3086860
2. To avoid putting extra tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/3086860

Answer (score 0):

The above ones weren't working for me. From comments in the documentation, it mentions

> You can't remove DOMNodes from a DOMNodeList as you're iterating over
> them in a foreach loop

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild

```
$domNodeList = $domDocument->getElementsByTagname('p');
    
$domElemsToRemove = array();

foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) {

  // ...do stuff with $domElement...

  $domElemsToRemove[] = $domElement;

}

foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){

  $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);

}
```

That style worked for me for removing some tags